# difference between cast and assignment int,char in C

Tags: c

Can anyone please explain what the difference between explicit conversion of integer to char

```
int i = 100;
char c2 = (char)i;
```

to assignment integer type to char

```
char i = 100;
```

thank you very much

Comment: A more entertaining question if you use 128 or larger for the value, btw.

Answer (score 6):

There is no behavioural difference.

However, some compilers may be configured to warn about implicit "narrowing" conversions.  So code like this may provoke a warning:

```
int i = ...;

char c = i;  // Implicit conversion
```